# Can a smart contract perform actions on a scheduled delay indefinitely?

Tags: smart-contract, deferred-transactions, time, schedule

I am pretty new to working with EOS, so please excuse my ignorance and improper terminology.

I am trying to repeatedly excecute a given action on a set time delay. For example, trying to submit a transaction every hour.

I have looked up several sources, and it seems like there are no tried and true methods for doing this. Chron seems like an option, but I was just wondering if there were any easy solutions I am missing. Let me know if there is anything unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be deferred transactions, but these have been since deprecated due to their unreliability.

One widely used product is croneos https://www.croneos.io/ which allows anyone to register their cron task with a contract and incentivize miners optionally with a token that can be used as gas, though I think you could just mine your own transactions.  Open sourced but unlicensed.

There is also LiquidApps's LiquidScheduler service: https://liquidapps.gitbook.io/liquidapps-documentation/dapp-network-services/dapp-network-services/liquidscheduler/getting-started-guide

This requires acquiring a token and staking it to DSPs (specialized nodes running LiquidApps tech) to provide the service.

Though recently we added a feature to allow for an indefinite interval versus only offering a deferred trx which is pretty cool.  Projects like the following use this service in production:

- Yup.io - https://www.etheos.xyz/
- Blockstart ecurve - http://bridge.blockstartdsp.com/
- https://bifrost.fi/